# Technical question about the fundamental system of solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question about the solution of some particular differential equation. Namely, I need to find $\lambda$, satisfying
\begin{align}
K_1 y^{iv}(x) + (\lambda a_2 - P_2)y''(x) + (P_3 - \lambda a_3)y(x) = 0, &\; x\in [0,1],\\ 
 y(0) = y(1) = y''(0) = y''(1) = 0.&
\end{align}
Here $P_2, P_3 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $K_1, a_2, a_3>0$.

I have done the following. At first, for simplicity, let us denote $K_2:=\lambda a_2 - P_2$, $K_3 = P_3 - \lambda a_3$.

Further, I consider the equation
\begin{equation}
K_1 \xi^4 + K_2\xi^2 + K_3 = 0.
\end{equation}
Making a substitution $\xi^2 = t$, I obtain a quadratic equation
\begin{equation}
K_1 t^2 + K_2 t + K_3 = 0
\end{equation}
with the roots
\begin{equation}
t_{1,2} = \frac{-K_2 \pm \sqrt{K_2^2 - 4K_1K3}}{2K_1}.
\end{equation}
Hence, I have $\xi_{1,2} = \pm\sqrt{t_1}$ and $\xi_{3,4} = \pm\sqrt{t_2}$. Therefore the original system with $\xi$ has four roots $\xi_1, -\xi_1, \xi_3, -\xi_3$. Now comes my question: would it be correct to conclude that the fundamental system of solutions is given by
\begin{cases} 
\{e^{\xi_1 x}, e^{-\xi_1 x}, e^{\xi_3 x}, e^{-\xi_3 x}\}, & \text{if}\quad \xi_1\neq\xi_3,\\
\{e^{\xi_1 x}, x e^{-\xi_1 x}\}, & \text{if}\quad \xi_1 = \xi_3.  
\end{cases}
For both cases above I built the Wronskian and check when it is not zero. That gives me some additional conditions on $\xi_i$.

I think that this question is rather trivial. I checked the literature: usually one knows the explicit roots before constructing the fundamental system. But here this is not the case. I don't know whether $\xi_i$ are complex or real. 
Thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it would be correct to conclude that, with some modifications. First, this is *a* fundamental system of solutions, not *the* fundamental system of solutions; any basis of the vector space of solutions can serve as a fundamental system of solutions. Second, in the case $\xi_1=\xi_3$ you've only listed two functions. I suspect that this is just a typo and you meant to also include $\mathrm e^{-\xi_1x}$ and $x\mathrm e^{\xi_1x}$?

Note that you also have boundary conditions, which select one particular solution in this space, namely $y\equiv0$.

It's not clear to me what you mean by "finding $\lambda$", as the equation has a solution for any value of $\lambda$.

Comment: Hi joriki! Thank you for your answer! In case $\xi_1 = \xi_3$ it was not a typo, but I realized later that I missed two solutions.

Comment: I was looking for such $\lambda$, that the differential equation above has a non-trivial solution.